# how to stop my object to skip by clicking and move just by touch

Tags: ios

I have some object on my screen view which moves by touch, but the problem is if I click somewhere else on my screen which has no object on, the last moved object skipped to that clicked position, anyone who know how I can be able to stop that? `PostView` contains code about my objects

**in .h file**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet PostView *pv;
```

**and .m file**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    viewArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: nil];
    pv.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100);
    pv.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [viewArray insertObject:pv atIndex:0];
    [self.view addSubview:pv];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint firstTouch = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    for (PostView *view in viewArray) {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, firstTouch)) {
            toMove = view;
        }
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    toMove.center = location;
   // [_delegate dragViewDidMove:self];
    // toMove.center = currentTouch;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    currentTouch = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    toMove.center = currentTouch;
}
```

Comment: Show us some code, please! :-)

Comment: Try to set `toMove` to `nil` after setting its `center` in `touchesEnded:withEvent:`.

Answer (score -1):

Set `toView` to `null` at the start of `touchesBegan:`. This ensures that if the user makes a touch that touches nothing (and so `toView` doesn't get set to anything deliberately), nothing will happen when the touch moves (the `setCenter:` message will be sent to `null` which will return `null` and have no side effects.)

Comment: May I ask who down voted and why they did so? I don't see any competing answers here, and nobody left any comments.